# HTML table Class codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter-3

In the following code (codeigniter documentation), how can i put an `<a href="">` on a specific field? Is it possible?

```
    $this->load->library('table');
    $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM my_table');
    echo $this->table->generate($query);
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I don't understand your question. What field? Where do you want to put anchor tag? Just place it in your view and you are done.

Comment: Refer this tutorial https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/table.html

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to do a `foreach` on your dataset and then amend the element using the `anchor` function which is an HTML helper within CI. Something like this:

```
foreach ($data as $=>$row){
    $data[$k]['field'] = anchor($row['URL'],$row['DisplayText']);
}
```